# How to make widget testing while using http.post

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I'm trying to use widget test for my project and test works fine till reach the point I use an http request in the actual page and it ,I think, ignore the request

```
final account = await http.post(
                  'http://10.0.2.2:5000/LogIn',
                  headers: <String, String>{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  },
                  body: json.encode({'email': email, 'password': password}),
                );
```

the account.body returns empty while it works well during using the emulator

```
 testWidgets("Successful Sign In", (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: SignIn()));

  //1-find widgets needed
  final textfieldemail = find.byKey(Key("emailtextformfield"));
  expect(textfieldemail, findsOneWidget);
  final textfieldpassword = find.byKey(Key("passwordtextformfield"));
  expect(textfieldpassword, findsOneWidget);
  final buttonsignin = find.byKey(Key("Signin"));
  expect(buttonsignin, findsOneWidget);

  //2-execute the actual test
  await tester.enterText(textfieldemail, "Weaam.wewe91@gmail.com");
  await tester.enterText(textfieldpassword, "Weaam@91");
  await tester.tap(buttonsignin);
  await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 5));
  //await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 5));
  //await _navigateToAccountHome(tester);

  //3-check results
  expect(find.byType(DeliveryHome), findsOneWidget);
});
```

});

I am not sure if I missed something I'm still beginner

Answer (score 9):

`testWidgets` by default uses a Mocked http class which will always return HTTP error 400.  This is likely why your code works in emulator, but not in tests.

To get actual HTTP responses from a web server prefix/setup before your test with:
`HttpOverrides.global = null;`

#### Example

Provided by [dnfield](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69574#issuecomment-720612453) (on Google Flutter team).

See [full github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69574)

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    // ↓ required to avoid HTTP error 400 mocked returns
    HttpOverrides.global = null;
  });
  testWidgets('http', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      final HttpClient client = HttpClient();
      final HttpClientRequest request =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://google.com'));

      final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      print(response.statusCode);  // Should get 200
    });
  });

  testWidgets('http2', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      final result = await get(Uri.parse('https://google.com'));
      print(result.statusCode); // Should get 200
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should't use http directly from widget. If so, your are merging UI with business logic as a bad practice. If both layers are not decoupled, you won't be able to mock the answers from server.

Once your code is decoupled, the [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package will help you.

In the test, you should write something like this:

```dart
// Unstubbed methods return null.
expect(cat.sound(), nullValue);

// Stub a mock method before interacting.
when(cat.sound()).thenReturn("Purr");
expect(cat.sound(), "Purr");

// You can call it again.
expect(cat.sound(), "Purr");

// Let's change the stub.
when(cat.sound()).thenReturn("Meow");
expect(cat.sound(), "Meow");

// You can stub getters.
when(cat.lives).thenReturn(9);
expect(cat.lives, 9);

// You can stub a method to throw.
when(cat.lives).thenThrow(RangeError('Boo'));
expect(() => cat.lives, throwsRangeError);

// We can calculate a response at call time.
var responses = ["Purr", "Meow"];
when(cat.sound()).thenAnswer((_) => responses.removeAt(0));
expect(cat.sound(), "Purr");
expect(cat.sound(), "Meow");
```

For more details, read the package readme.